# Quoting and concatenating a fish function argument

Tags: fish

I keep destroying and provisioning VMs, so ssh frequently complains that I'm being **`NASTY`**. Mmmm...

Anyways, I wrote a fish function to banish the offending key on the line it tells me with `sed`:

```
function forgethost
   sed -i.bak {$argv}d ~/.ssh/known_hosts
end
```

but I'd like to keep the command quoted to protect me against (injecting) myself a little bit. When I wrap it in `''`, it then doesn't replace `$argv`. Also, I'd prefer to just grab the first argument `[0]`, but when I add that it also doesn't expand.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `~/.ssh/config` entry for the VMs you're continually recreating.  Example below.  Means you don't have to keep hacking your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

```
Host test-vm-1
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Comment: It's across a range of IPs, can I say `Host 10.11.12.13/24` or the like?

Comment: Yes : can say `Host 10.11.12.?`.  See man page for ssh_config, section PATTERNS.

Comment: [Online man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5#PATTERNS) for convienence. `/24` may have been a bit too easy, mine is actually a `/22` and a `/23` so might need to cobble together multiple imprecise patterns.

Comment: Could always cobble together some command to drop the explicit IPs into the config file.   e.g. in the case of /24 : `echo {1..255}|xargs -n 1 printf "Host 1.2.3.%d\n   StrictHostKeyChecking no\n"`

Answer (score 1):

> When I wrap it in '', it then doesn't replace $argv.

What you want is double-quotes, i.e. `"$argv"`. This is the same as in other shells.

> Also, I'd prefer to just grab the first argument [0], but when I add that it also doesn't expand.

In fish, the first element of a list has the index 1, so you want `$argv[1]`.

Together that means

```
function forgethost
   sed -i.bak "$argv[1]"d ~/.ssh/known_hosts
end
```

Of course you could also add error handling if more than one argument has been given with

```
if set -q argv[2] # yes, no $
    echo "This only accepts one argument" >&2
    return 1
endt
```